# Why am I getting an error after scraping the last item of the web page?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I made a program that retrieves the product names and prices from newEgg, however after the last product on the webpage is processed, I get an error saying "Attribute Error: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'strong'. I'm fairly certain its a null pointer error since the loop is running through all of the web page elements, however I've tried iterating to the itemContainers-1, as well as setting a breakpoint in the loop at itemcontainers-1, and it still doesnt work. Also, where should i put the Client.close(), at the end right?

```py
import bs4
#uReq is our arbitrary shorthand for urllib.request
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

#The URL we plan to use
my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/'

#uReq(my_url) opens up web client
Client = uReq(my_url)
#uClient.read dumps everything out of the url
html_page = Client.read()
Client.close()


page_soup = soup(html_page, "html.parser")
itemContainers= page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"item-container"})

for i in range(0,len(itemContainers)):
    if i is len(itemContainers)-1:
        {
            breakpoint
        }
    #itemTitles is a list of all of the titles found on the web page
    itemTitles = page_soup.findAll("a", {"class": "item-title"})

    divWithPriceInfo = itemContainers[i].find("ul", "price")
    left_Dec = divWithPriceInfo.strong.text
    right_Dec = divWithPriceInfo.sup.text
    stringStrong = str(left_Dec)
    stringSup = str(right_Dec)
    print(itemTitles[i].text)
    print(stringStrong + stringSup)
```

Comment: Running this code does not generate an error.  Is it supposed to?

Comment: As Trenton mentioned it, Code is running fine. Can you post your error log (with line info etc.,) in the question?